# Authorize attribute - how should I use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I used `[Authorize(Roles = "Admininstrators")]` to prevent users from accessing the web address under this authorization, but what should I do if I want to authorize this permission after successful login? I don't see the method on the official website. I don't know how to authorize admininstrators

[image]

new
[image]
[image]

download
https://pan.bbhxwl.com/s/AbcG

Comment: When the user is logged in, if they have the Administrators role, they will be able to access methods in `HomeController`. Also, please provide code as text, only using screenshots for illustrative purposes.

Comment: https://pan.bbhxwl.com/s/AbcG

Comment: Check a few well-voted questions, and you'll notice that **none** of them use screenshots of zip downloads to communicate their problem.

Answer (score 0):

To use `[Authorize(Role)]`, you must add a role to the user as in the method `EnsureRole() -> await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0

---

If you want to use claims for authorization, then check out this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0

you need to use `[Authorization(Policy)]` instead of `[Authorization(Role)]` and specify the necessary policies in Startup.cs

```
services.Add authorization(parameters =>
{
  options.Add a policy ("Required Administrator Role",
  policy => policy.Required role ("Administrator"));
});
```

Comment: [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Index2()
        {
           
            EnsureRole()->await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
            return Content("2");
        }

Comment: I still don't understand. I won't send pictures.

Comment: Look at the picture in the question I edited again. How to modify it?

Comment: https://pan.bbhxwl.com/s/AbcG